# Is it possible to declare static vaiables and functions in a Scala Trait?

Tags: scala, oop, traits

I know that one can use a companion ojbect to declare static variables and functions for a Class in Scala, but is there a way to do declare static variables/funcions in a Trait?

Comment: No, you can't. Specially because **Scala** does not really has the concept of **static**, it only has values. Now, we all know that `objects` are compiled down to static fields, but that is just a runtime detail. - If you want something to be created only one time, you would need to define it on an `object`. On your trait you can have a reference to that val on that object if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a companion object for a `trait` in the same way that you have a companion object for a `class`.

So you can't declare `static` values inside the `trait` because Scala does not work that way, but you can achieve the same thing using the companion object.